# When could be the word "zweckmäßig" used?

Tags: word-usage

The word '*zweckmäßig*' has the meaning 'expedient' and 'suitable'.

With which topics could be this word used mainly?

Please provide some examples if it is possible.

Comment: *Zweck* means *purpose*, and *zweckmäßig* means *purposeful*.

Comment: I suggest you look at the example sentences in the dictionary of your choice, or look at the words in context, e. g. at https://www.linguee.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used for evaluation purpose. (Mainly engineering)

The solution is appropriate.

> Die Lösung ist zweckmäßig.

The design fulfills its purpose.

> Die Konstruktion ist zweckmäßig.

Answer (score 3):

> Etwas, das *zweckmäßig* ist, erfüllt einen Zweck.
>
> ⇆
>
> Something *purposeful* fulfills a purpose.

Consequently, whenever you talk about something purposeful, you can characterize it as being *zweckmäßig*.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the main part of that word: *Zweck*, which means *purpose*.

So I would translate it as *purposeful* or *expedient*.

If something is purposeful, that can mean something is *suitable* or *appropriate* too, but those translations would be a little too general, IMO.